# jQLite strange behaviour: element.css('right')

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I've made the painfull experience that jQlite does not work like jQuery.
The following statement is plain wrong:

> jqLite is a tiny, **API-compatible** **subset** of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM

If I set in my css the

```
.pane2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
}
```

The following will work with jQuery but **not** with jQlite. Is this a bug or is this just undocumented, that jQlite can't read from percent calculated values?

```
var right = parseInt(pane2.elem.css('right'));
```

In jQlite is `right` NaN. In jQuery is `right`the correct integer value.

Comment: What does "The following will work with jQuery but not with jQlite" mean exactly? What is happening and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems jQlite lacks this feature and it's just undocumented.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2866